# Visual Basic Application Continous split text in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my sample output of split text using textbox and Button in Active X Control. As you can see here "Hello World!" was inputted in the text box and the output was splitted text.

But what I want is everytime that I input some data on textbox it gives splitted text continuously in other words the cell keeps the historical data that I inputted on the textbox.

Because it just give splitted text but not keeping it when entering new data on the textbox. I Want this output because I will use all of historical splitted text and count it after counting the most occurrence I will make a descriptive graph for my project

Here's my code:

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim TextString As String, WArray() As String, Counter As Integer, Strg As String

    TextString = TextBox1
    WArray() = Split(TextString, " ")

    For Counter = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)
        Strg = WArray(Counter)
        Cells(Counter + 2, 1).Value = Trim(Strg)
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

[image: sampleoutput1]

[image: sample output2]

Comment: This is very simply solved - Where do you want to store the original input?

Comment: I want to store all of historical data to another worksheet sir

Comment: Answer below :)

Comment: Sir it works but what should i do to replace the word "test" to my texbox1 where the user can input any data

Comment: Heres the sample output i try to change the word "test" but it gives this output

inputted data: programmers and developers
output:

programmers,
and,
developers,
developers

Comment: Sorry about that - replace "Test" with `TextString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without looping

***Edit:*** Updated to append to end of column

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim WArray As Variant

    WArray = Split(TextBox1, " ")
    With Sheets("DatabaseStorage")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(WArray) + IIf(LBound(WArray) = 0, 1, 0)) = Application.Transpose(WArray)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It splits but not continously stores the whole data inputted in the textbox1. my expected output is every time i put data on textbox whether the same data or not it can store the data splitted.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying. Are you saying you don't want to overwrite the cells that have data in them?

Comment: Yes exactly sir tom that is what  i want to do. But unfortunately i can't find some good tutorial about my problem hmmm

Comment: I've updated it to append to the end of column `A` Have a look at this for reference [source](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Comment: Hi sir tom thanks for your help it works finally the output that i am expecting. This answer means a lot for us thanks

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend changing the `ActiveSheet` to declaring explicitly the sheet that you're outputting to

Comment: Sir tom what if i want to change the activesheet to another sheet?

Comment: Change `With ActiveSheet` to `With Sheets('xxxx')` or replace it with the vba name (You can find this on the left hand side of the vba editor under `Microsoft Excel Objects`. If you tell me your sheet name I'll update it

Comment: Sir it works again Haha, im so shy to ask you but i need this thanks again :) here's the code


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call SplitText
End Sub
Sub SplitText()
    Dim WArray As Variant
    Dim TextString As String
    TextString = TextBox1
    WArray = Split(TextBox1, " ")
    With Sheets("DatabaseStorage")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(WArray) + IIf(LBound(WArray) = 0, 1, 0)) = Application.Transpose(WArray)
    End With
    
End Sub

Comment: Sir just wanna ask you again i hope you don't mind, we have a lot of data 500 rows and we just want to collect the noun, adjective and pronoun is it possible in excel vba ?

Comment: [I'd have to refer you to this or start a new question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036428/extracting-the-noun-adjective-words-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SplitText()
Dim TextString As String, WArray() As String, Counter As Integer, Strg As String
TextString = TextBox1
WArray() = Split(TextString, " ")

For Counter = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)
    Strg = WArray(Counter)
    Cells(Counter + 2, 1).Value = Trim(Strg)
Next Counter

Sheets("Original values").Range("A" & Sheets("Original values").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = TextString

End Sub
```